# Unir dos scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera unir estos scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#value").change(function(){
             var idvalue = $('#value').val();
             $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>llamo controlador", {
                 idvalue : idvalue});
         });


        });
</script>
```

con este otro:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#contenedorPaginacion").load("<?php echo base_url() ?>llamo controlador");
         $(document).on("click", "#pagination-digg li a", function(e){
          e.preventDefault();          
            var href = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#contenedorPaginacion").load(href);
      });

 });
</script>
```

En base al primero ejecute el segundo (llamo controlador) es el mismo controlador.

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias, llevo poco pero me gusta, gracias] @Maghdiel y @lois6b, no se si sea lo correcto pero de este modo me funciono

```
$("#value").change(function(){
          var idvalue = $('#value').val();
           $("#contenedorPaginacion").load("<?php echo base_url() ?>llamo controlador",
            {idvalue : idvalue});
       });
       $(document).on("click", "#pagination-digg li a", function(e){
           e.preventDefault();          
           var href = $(this).attr("href");
           $("#contenedorPaginacion").load(href);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que, cuando se cargue el primer script, mande a llamar la otra función, añádelo como función y llamas la función. Porque en sí a mí me parece que únicamente lo debes de incluir todo dentro de 1 sólo `document.ready` y poner los dos tal y como están.

Comment: Hola Maghdiel, esto no es una respuesta, es un comentario. Se que aun te falta reputacion para comentar pero cada cosa en su sitio. Procura responder a preguntas que no requieran clarificacion del autor. Animo hasta los 50 rep ^^

Comment: si como lo añado como función para llamar la función.... el segundo script funciona perfecto realiza la paginacion, pero necesito los parámetros para la búsqueda especifica el primero me los obtiene. al hacer un cambio en el selec...

Comment: Mejor dale  a [edit] para aportar una respuesta como lo indicado en [answer], pues esto es solamente un comentario.

Comment: @MaghdielCampos Una respuesta así, donde se describe qué hacer puede beneficiarse enormemente si agregaras el código mostrando cómo quedarían las 2 funciones dentro del `$(document).ready()` ... Por más que sea sólo copiar el código de la pregunta, ordenarla como debe ir mostraría exactamente qué estás diciendo.... Estamos en un sitio de preguntas y respuestas de programación, ¡queremos código! ;-)

Comment: ok muchas gracias por los consejos no sabia es apenas mi primera respuesta y ni quiera se que usuario hizo la pregunta jaja.